# 'It is not possible to have a process in which the entropy of an isolated system is decreased'. can you please explain this statement?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

> It is not possible to have a process in which the entropy of an isolated system is decreased

Does that mean, if we increase the volume of a gas, entropy of gas increases, now when we decrease the volume of gas to its original volume, the entropy of gas comes back to its original state, but the excess entropy is transferred to the surroundings?

Comment: Define what your *isolated system* is in the context of the question.

Comment: Isolated system here refers to a system where there is no exchange of matter or energy with the surroundings

Comment: let me repeat it, in your question what is isolated from what?

Comment: I'm so sorry, isolated system here refers to one of the three types of systems in thermodynamics: open, closed, and isolated.
An open system can exchange both energy and matter with its surroundings.
A closed system, on the other hand, can exchange only energy with its surroundings, not matter
An isolated system is one that cannot exchange either matter or energy with its surroundings.

Comment: let me try once more, is the gas isolated or is the cylinder isolated?

Comment: The cylinder is isolated...

Comment: If the cylinder is isolated then it neither can expand or contract by external work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean, if we increase the volume of a gas, entropy of gas increases, now when we decrease the volume of gas to its original volume, the entropy of gas comes back to its original state, but the excess entropy is transferred to the surroundings?

Since you've said that the system is *isolated*, i.e., that it can transfer neither energy nor mass to or from its environment, then it's also true that *entropy* can't be transferred to or from the environment.  This mean that the only processes that can occur are internal, *spontaneous* processes, i.e., processes that occur due to temperature gradients, pressure gradients, etc. within the system.  Such processes necessarily *increase* entropy within the system and are hence irreversible. This means that the system actually *can't* reset to its original state without some interaction with its environment.

In OP's question, OP keeps saying "we", and that's telling: the point is that for "us" to reset the system back to its original volume/pressure/temperature (state!), "we" (the environment of the system!) have to do something.

Comment: Hey there!
I really appreciate your answer, can you clarify me this question, is entropy transferred in different ways, for eg, in the form of energy, so that the surrounding takes it up and in turn increases its randomness? Once again thank you for your answer.

Comment: Entropy is a state variable and by definition it can not be transferred through the boundary of the system in the way OP described it does. On the other hand, heat and work are process variables and can be transferred through the boundary of the system.

Comment: @User198 Yes, I agree, although out there in the world the language is used.  Of course the idea is that what is transferred is energy via heating, say, and the resulting change in entropy of the environment is $Q/T_{\textrm{env}$ (for fixed temperature environment), which is not necessarily the negative of the change in entropy of the system (only true if the transfer happens reversibly).

Answer (score 2):

Entropy of an isolated system can only increase (unlike pressure, temperature, volume, etc.) Thus, if we increase the volume of the gas, two things may happen:

- *Reversible process* - the entropy doesn't change, and we can return the system to its initial state
- *Irreversible process* - the entropy increases (e.g., due to fast expansion or squeezing) and the system cannot return to the initial state - we may return the volume to the original volume, but the other parameters would not be the same as in the beginning, e.g., the temperature would be higher.

Comment: Hey there!, thank you for taking your time to answer my question, I really appreciate it, cheers!

Comment: @AvaneeshB if you find my answer useful, feel free to upvote it (I see that you already accepted the other one.)

Comment: I tried upvoting both the answers, but I need 15 reputations to do so, sorry. Thanks once again!